# How can I flush the endline character in java?

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm new to java and I made my first "program" -- a simple input/output program that spits out what you enter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Input{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      int zip;
      int a;
      double e = 2.718281828459045;
      String name;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter your zip code: ");
      zip = in.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
      name = in.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
      a = in.nextInt();

      System.out.println(name+", "+"your zip code is "+zip+" and e*"+a+" is "+e*a);

     }
}
```

So when I run this, I enter the zip code and it goes to the integer input next. I suspect that the input stream is swallowing the endline character once I press enter. Any quick fixes or am I just java-stupid?

Thanks, SO!

Comment: Your guess is correct, you just need an extra nextLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In between

```
System.out.println("Enter your zip code: ");
zip = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
name = in.nextLine();
```

add an extra `in.nextLine()`. So

```
System.out.println("Enter your zip code: ");
zip = in.nextInt();

in.nextLine(); // consume dangling eol characters

System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
name = in.nextLine();
```

The method `Scanner#nextInt()` only reads the bytes required to make an `int`, not anything that comes after it. If you pressed enter after entering the integer, you will have a dangling carriage return/new line character. You will need a `Scanner#nextLine()` to get rid of it.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this solution because it relies on there invariably being a dangling carriage return... Reading it in either way and *then* checking for a blank line seems more kosher.

Comment: The non-assigning `in.nextLine()` line relies on the input always having a dangling EOL... I suppose it's reasonable to make that assumption, but it might be smart to assign it to *something* in order to check and ensure that it is indeed empty.